# Identifying duplicates with different IDs

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(26312)
id <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 9)
wrc <- round(runif(36, 20, 100))
wrc <- c(wrc, wrc[10:18])
x <- rep(1:9, 5)
dat <- data.frame(id, wrc, x)
```

In this data set, id 2 and id 5 contain the exact same data but with different IDs. This can be verified by running,

```
dat[dat$id == 2, ]
dat[dat$id == 5, ]
```

I have a much larger data set, with 4321 IDs, and I want to remove these duplicates because even though they have different IDs, they really are duplicates.

Presently I am do a combo of really awful and extremely slow `for()` and `while()` loops. In English, what the code is doing is subsetting an id and then comparing that id to every other id that I have subsetted within a while loop. When I find a duplicate, meaning all the rows of data are identical, it should throw away the first id that is a duplicate.  The resulting `cleaned_data` is what I want, it is just unbearable slow to get there. Because it takes roughly 1 minute to do a comparison when I have 4321 ids, so that's about 4321 minutes to run this awful loop. Can someone help?

```
library("dplyr")
id_check = 1:5
cleaned_data <- data.frame()
for(i in id_check){
  compare_tmp <- dat %>% filter(id == i) 
  compare_check <- compare_tmp %>% select(wrc, x)
  duplicate = FALSE
  if(i == length(id_check)){
    cleaned_data <- rbind(cleaned_data, compare_tmp)
    break
  } else {
    id_tmp = i + 1
  }
  while(duplicate == FALSE){
    check <- dat %>% filter(id == id_tmp) %>% select(wrc, x)
    if(nrow(check) == 0) break
    duplicate = identical(compare_check, check)
    id_tmp = id_tmp + 1
    if(id_tmp == (length(id_check) + 1)) {
      break
    }
  }
  if(duplicate == FALSE){
    cleaned_data <- rbind(cleaned_data, compare_tmp)
  } 
}
cleaned_data
```

This is in response to why duplicated won't work. Below ids 2 and 5 are not the same subjects because there data aren't always identical.

```
set.seed(26312)
id <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 9)
wrc <- round(runif(36, 20, 100))
wrc <- c(wrc, wrc[c(1, 11:18)])
x <- rep(1:9, 5)
dat <- data.frame(id, wrc, x)
dat[dat$id == 2,]
dat[dat$id == 5,]
```

If I run `dat[!duplicated(dat[2:3]),]` it removes id 5, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Does your real data have more columns? Or is this example realistic in that there is an id column, a within-id index, and a single value column?

Comment: "If I run dat[!duplicated(dat[2:3]),] it removes id 5, when it shouldn't." It removes ID 5 because first row ID1 is exactly same as first in ID5. So isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Hakki no, this is a group-wise de-duplication. The `wrc` and `x` columns  where `ID = 5` are identical to the `wrc` and `x` columns where `ID = 2`, so the entire `ID = 2` group should be removed, and the entire `ID = 5` group should be kept.

Comment: aah, got it. Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: Actually, I would have wanted to keep both `ID = 2` and `ID = 5` and there were more columns of data. However, @Gregor response below seems to do this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column structure is accurate, you could convert to wide format for duplicate detection:

```
dat_wide = reshape2::dcast(dat, id ~ x, value.var = "wrc")
dupes = dat_wide$id[duplicated(dat_wide[-1], fromLast = T)]

no_dupes = dat[!dat$id %in% dupes, ]
```

Comment: Wow. The solution was so obvious it hurts my head.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  split(dat, dat$id)[!duplicated(lapply(split(dat[2:3], dat$id), `rownames<-`, NULL), fromLast = TRUE)]
)
```

This splits by `id`, identifies duplicates, then binds again the non-duplicates.

---

**Edit**
Since time is of the essence here, I ran a benchmark of the solutions so far:

```
set.seed(26312)
p <- 4321
id <- rep(1:p, each = 9)
dats <- replicate(p %/% 2, round(runif(9, 20, 100)), simplify = FALSE)
wrc <- unlist(sample(dats, p, replace = TRUE))
x <- rep(1:9, times = p)
dat <- data.frame(id, wrc, x)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = {
    do.call(
      rbind,
      split(dat, dat$id)[!duplicated(lapply(split(dat[2:3], dat$id), `rownames<-`, NULL), fromLast = TRUE)]
    )
  },
  tidyr = {
    as_tibble(dat) %>% 
      nest(-id) %>%
      filter(!duplicated(data, fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
      unnest()
  },
  reshape = {
    dat_wide = reshape2::dcast(dat, id ~ x, value.var = "wrc")
    dupes = dat_wide$id[duplicated(dat_wide[-1], fromLast = T)]
    no_dupes = dat[!dat$id %in% dupes, ]
  },
  times = 10L
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min        lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#     base 892.8239 980.36553 1090.87505 1096.12514 1187.98810 1232.47244    10   c
#    tidyr 944.8156 953.10558  977.71756  976.83703  990.58672 1033.27664    10  b 
#  reshape  49.9955  50.13347   52.20539   51.91833   53.91568   55.64506    10 a
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(dat) %>% 
  nest(-id) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(data, fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
  unnest()

# # A tibble: 36 x 3
#       id   wrc     x
#    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1     1    53     1
#  2     1    44     2
#  3     1    70     3
#  4     1    31     4
#  5     1    67     5
#  6     1    50     6
#  7     1    70     7
#  8     1    40     8
#  9     1    52     9
# 10     3    95     1
# # ... with 26 more rows
```

(Note: not sure about the Stackoverflow policy about multiple answers, but this one is different enough to deserve a separate answer IMHO (if it's not, please say so and I'll edit my initial answer and delete this one).

Comment: Definitely different enough!